# android TableLayout adding rows dynamically adds only the last row

Tags: java, android, user-interface, tablelayout, tablerow

after reading tens of threads on StackOverflow.
I'm trying to add dynamically rows to a table-layout. 
The problem is, the only one row is added dynamically, and it is spanning on all of the page.
This is my code:

```
package com.example.trashproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{


    private static final int ROWS =2;
    private static final int COLS = 10;
    private static final String TAG = null;
    private TableLayout mTable;
    private View[][] mCircles;
    private boolean[][] mData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        makeTable();

    }

    private void makeTable() {
        mTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

        TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        rowParams.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        rowParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        mCircles = new View[ROWS][COLS];
        TableRow row;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                mCircles[i][j] = new View(this);
                mCircles[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_circle);
                row.addView(mCircles[i][j]);
            }
            mTable.addView(row);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TableRow >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEXT"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEXT"/>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

calendar_month_grid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    />
```

small_circle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <size android:width="15dp"
        android:height="1dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

</shape>
```

Your help appreciated...

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I'd get rid of the table row definitions in your xml file for the table.

Comment: @Kristy welsh: I've added it just to check if it is only the dynmic added rows not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the "View" that is giving you  a problem. Try replacing it with an ImageView (try it) and I think it will work. If you really want View (not sure why) then set the min height and min width to something like 10dp.

It happened to me once that empty View with wrap content spans the whole page. It is pushing the rest of your rows out of the screen

Comment: Yes you can do that with imageview. Create the image view programmatically and do Setimageresourcse or setImageSrc.. Can't remember the exact syntax. You will get the same effect. Try it to eliminate at least the potential "view" problem

Comment: I figured it out, I didn't set the Views layout params. I thought I inflate it. but I didn't